# Why does Unicode have 2 spaces? What's the difference?

Tags: unicode, character, ascii, whitespace

I just saw that Unicode has 2 space characters within its first 200 entries: `0x20` and `0xa0`

I know the entity of `0xa0` from HTML (it's `&nbsp;` there) and I know that `0x20` is also a space-character in the ASCII table.

So what's the difference between them and why do we need 2 of them?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html) helps you!

Comment: "nbsp" is short for no-break space.

Comment: To identify a Unicode codepoint, use the notation U+0020, U+00A0 or [U+1F6B2](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f6b2/index.htm). The notation 0x20 usually denotes bytes, which is in the realm of serialized code units for a codepoint using a particular character encoding for a particular character set. Or, for HTML or XML, numeric character entity references like &#x0020; &#x00a0; &#x1f6b2; convey the same thing. Of course, when you are intending to show bytes, a byte string, or a character string, maybe indicate which language, and always which character encoding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's about line breaks, or in particular, word wrapping.

U+0020 SPACE is for when you want a word separator in a place where a line break is acceptable.

U+00A0 NBSP is for when you want a word separator in a place where a line break is undesirable.

See Table 1 in [UNICODE LINE BREAKING ALGORITHM](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/tr14-43.html).

> ```
> GL    Non-breaking (“Glue”)   CGJ, NBSP, ZWNBSP   Prohibit line breaks before and after
> ```
>
> ```
> SP    Space                   SPACE               Enable indirect line breaks
> ```